# Rotate mapCanvas with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsmapcanvas

I'm trying to implement within some code on PyQGIS, a way to rotate the view of my mapCanvas

I want it to work the same way as the GUI present on the bottom right corner

[image: GUI way to rotate image]

However when I run the following code I do not get the same result as if I had manually interacted with the GUI

```
iface.mapCanvas().rotate(90)
```

The result from running the code
[image: result from the code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.setRotation()` instead:

```
iface.mapCanvas().setRotation(90)
```